# what is the difference between extra_context and get_context_data(**kwargs) in django CBVs

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I'm using **Django CBVs** and confused about differences between `extra_context` Class attribute and `get_context_data(**kwargs)` method. Although according to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#contextmixin) you can use both but which one is better to use?

can anyone help me to clear the problem ???

I use this class attribute in a `DetailView` subclass and it worked .

Django 2.2 version  .

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you still has this doubt, but I recently had an issue by using extract_context in a production environment, specifically on a AWS EC2 instance using Django 2.2 and Python 3.6, I thought that using a QuerySet on extra_context will update automatically in production as it did on dev environment but in case you need a QuerySet update in your context you better use get_context_data.

Bottom line if you need a fixed value use extra_context otherwise use get_context_data.

Answer (score 0):

They both do the same functionality, except that in `get_context_data` to get prev data you should call `super` and update that dict; cause you don't want to lose prev data in context.

But `extra_context` will do the same but no need to call super and you can call it in url like `TemplateView.as_view(extra_context={'title': 'Custom Title'})`.

So to sum up, `extra_context` is just a faster with less code to update your context data in CBV.
Also to **note**, `extra_context` will be used as an attribute, but `get_context_data` is the method for CBVs.